# How to remove grub bootloader on a locked down laptop?

Tags: bootloader, delete, grub-efi

Ok so I installed ubuntu on a usb stick but it also put grub on my school laptop, I cant open diskmgt on windows, how can I delete the bootloader using linux?

The only thing I can think of is taking the m.2 out of the laptop, putting it in my pc, and deleting it there.

Comment: 1. deleting GRUB will make you unable to boot Linux 2. How did installing Linux on a USB stick cause GRUB to end up on your m.2 drive? 3. if GRUB replaced the windows bootloader, then deleting it will mean you can't boot Windows either 4. You should be able to use a live USB (like the one you used to install Ubuntu) to see/modify disks in your laptop

Comment: The usb stick didn’t do anything to your laptop - but *you* probably did. That’s not a criticism, but to reverse what’s happened you need to remember exactly what you did - and add those details to your question so someone can help.

Comment: @esther how would i go about deleting grub bootloader via a live usb environment? I am preparing a live usb for this right now. The reason grub is on my m.2 is because i messed up while installing and didnt change the default bootloader installation device.

Also, im not sure if i can delete it with a live usb because i recall it saying "encrypted volume" when i first used a live usb on this laptop.

Comment: Update

So I used Gparted to delete the EFI partition but it mustve been the wrong one because now there is no bootable media on the m.2. Im just going to tell the school that "it just did that" and let them reinstall windows on it lol.

Comment: See (3) of my first comment: possibly GRUB replaced the windows bootloader entirely, in which case deleting it makes you unable to boot Windows either.